# Could not autowire. No beans of 'MyUserDetailsService' type found

Tags: java

[The IDEA compiler reports an error, but the project can run normally. What is the reason?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBAlX.png)
The IDEA compiler reports an error, but the project can run normally. What is the reason?

```java
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Resource
    MyRBACService myRBACService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                                      throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //加载基础用户信息
        MyUserDetails myUserDetails = myRBACService.findByUserName(username);

        //加载用户角色列表
        List<String> roleCodes = myRBACService.findRoleByUserName(username);

        List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String roleCode : roleCodes){
          //通过用户角色列表加载用户的资源权限列表
          authorities.addAll(myRBACService.findApiByRoleCode(roleCode));
        }

        //角色是一个特殊的权限，ROLE_前缀
        roleCodes = roleCodes.stream()
                .map(rc -> "ROLE_" +rc)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        authorities.addAll(roleCodes);

        myUserDetails.setAuthorities(
                AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(
                        String.join(",",authorities)
                )
        );


        return myUserDetails;
    }
}
```

```java
public class JWTAutoConfigure {

    @Resource
    private JwtProperties jwtProperties;


    @Bean
    public JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil() {
        return new JwtTokenUtil(jwtProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(
            JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
            MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(
                this.jwtProperties,jwtTokenUtil,myUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Autowiring is a runtime operation, so compiler is obviously unable to detect it. It's probably a warning from you IDE

Comment: I think there is no need for automatic assembly when receiving parameters, just like the previous JwtTokenUtil parameter did not report Could not autowire. Can this kind of error be ignored?

Comment: Invalidate Cache and Restart IDE